# ODBC connection error

Tags: windows-server-2008

I have two Windows Server 2008 R2:

A: Run SQL Express 2008
B: Run Hyper-V

I am trying to create an ODBC connection from server B to server A. Server B has a performance counter to monitor the VM bandwidth, the data will be logged into a sql database on server A.

After creating a data collector set in performance monitor on server B, and configured it to log to SQL database, it says 'when attempting to start the Data Collector set the following Error occurred :call to SqlAllocConnect failed with %1 '. I've encountered the same error when I use NT authentication and SQL authentication on server B, but no problem with NT authentication on server A. Server A has problem with SQL authentication too. Any idea how to identify the problem? Thanks.